# Some ng-app issues

Tags: angularjs

I have two questions:

1. If we have more than one **ng-app** which one creates the **$rootScope**? Is it the first one? The scopes created from the other **ng-app**s are *child scopes*? Is it necessary sometimes to use more than one **ng-app**?
2. In which way do I have access to a module created `with no explicit name after ng-app`? Is it possible to add a controller to this kind of module and how?

   ```
     angular.module('?????????', [])         
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope','$log', function              
    MyController($scope,$log) {...}]);
   ```

Comment: I think there is no need to use more than one `ng-app`. and you can create `$rootScope` in it. and I am not getting your second question

Comment: I don't think you can create a module with no name.

Comment: I would guess there are two `$rootScopes`. I think the traditional use case for multiple apps is when you wish to slowly integrate Angular into an existing application. Think about the scenario where the apps are siblings of each other in the DOM ... the parent element is not part of any Angular app, where would you put the `$rootScope`?